# Is the usage of “where” in this sentence acceptable？

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, pronouns, conjunctions

Is the usage of “where” in this sentence acceptable？

> Each holiday we arrange ten volunteers to teach for three weeks in rural primary school ***where*** mostly understaffed and severely lacking in educational resources.

I just wonder whether it is possible to omit (where <strike>it is</strike>)

Comment: I don't find it acceptable. Assuming that more than one school is involved, I would suggest _rural primary schools, which are mostly understaffed..._ or, better still, _most of which are understaffed..._

Answer (score 0):

No

> Each holiday we arrange ten volunteers to teach for three weeks in
> rural primary school, **which are mostly** understaffed and severely lacking in
> educational resources.

Or

> Each holiday we arrange ten volunteers to teach for three weeks in
> rural primary school, **most of which are** understaffed and severely lacking in
> educational resources.

Comment: But using "rural primary school" like that is ungrammatical - it should be in the plural as there are multiple schools. (In other contexts you could use "a rural primary school").